# Consecutive compositions in exact triangles are zero

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

1) In Weibel's *Homological Algebra* the definition of a triangle
$$A \overset{u}{\to} B \overset{v}{\to} C \overset{w}{\to} T(A)$$
does not include the condition that $vu, wv, T(u)w = 0$ and the statement of [TR3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category#TR_3) includes only the hypothesis that the square from $X$ to $Y'$ commutes:
$$\begin{matrix} X & \to & Y & \to & Z & \to & T(X) \\ \downarrow && \downarrow &&&& \downarrow \\ X' & \to & Y' & \to & Z' & \to & T(X')\end{matrix}$$
There is then an exercise (10.2.1) to show that TR3 implies that consecutive maps are zero, by using TR3 on
$$\begin{matrix} A & = & A & \to & 0 & \to & T(A) \\ || && \downarrow &&&& || \\ A & \to & B & \to & C & \to & T(A)\end{matrix}$$

2) In Neeman's *Triangulated Categories* the definition of a triangle does include the condition that $vu, wv, T(u)w = 0$ and the statement of TR3 includes the hypothesis that the entire diagram commutes, in particular the square from $Y$ to $T(X')$ must commute before the existence of the map $Z \to Z'$ is given.  Neeman then remarks (1.1.3) that the assumptions $vu, wv, T(u)w = 0$ are superfluous, they are implied by TR3 using the same argument that Weibel suggests.

My questions:

1. In Neeman's argument that the conditions $vu, wv, T(u)w = 0$ are superfluous doesn't he need to know in the above diagram that the square from $A$ to $T(A)$ commutes, i.e., that the composition $A \to B \to C \to T(A)$ is zero?
2. What is the correct definition of a triangle and the correct formulation of TR3?  Do you need to assume that consecutive maps compose to zero or not and do you need to assume commutativity of the square from $Y$ \to $T(X')$ or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Neeman's book, the commutative diagram in his version of (TR3) only contains the vertical arrows $X\to X'$ and $Y\to Y'$, not the arrow $T(X)\to T(X')$ (probably for exactly this reason), so he's only requiring that the left hand square commutes, not the rectangle involving $Y$ and $T(X')$.

Comment: Well I'll be.  I totally misread it.